# How to control sexual desires? (need motivation)

Tags: sex, jannah, oaths

As salam alaikum
PLZ HELP AND PRAY 4 ME
How to control sexual desires if aiming for the highest Heaven (jannat e firdous), made an oath to Allah to never repeat it and a teenager therefore unable to marry or fast due to worldy and educational obligations?
Jazakallah 
Allah Alam

Answer (score 1):

Marriage is the best avenue for those with high sexual desire as our prophet(sallallahu alayhi wa sallam) recommended this(below hadith)

***Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) when he said: “O young men, whoever among you can afford to, let him get married, for it is more effective in lowering the gaze and in guarding one’s chastity. Whoever cannot afford it, then let him fast, for it will be a shield for him.”***

Lowering your gaze not just when you see opposite genders face to face but also when you watch movies and pictures in magazine.

***And tell the believing women to lower their gaze (from looking at forbidden things), and protect their private parts (from illegal sexual acts)”
[al-Noor 24:31]***

Stop thinking and daydreaming about opposite genders and sexual nature.  Keep yourself busy with halal activities so you have less time to waste for sexual desire.  Be patience and ask Allah Most Great for help.

And Allah Knows Best.

Answer (score 0):

You should fast as many days possible to lower your sexual desires until you can get married.

Answer (score 0):

I second the fast.
You need to weaken your body in order to weaken the desires.

I don't know if it's allowed or effective, but I heard about chaste-berry? (vitex).
Nowadays it's mainly about regulating women hormones, but in old times monks were using it to tame their urges.

Answer (score 0):

There is type of foods that reduces the sexual desires and other types increases it. Fill your time with useful things, read books, go to the gym, do push ups. Something that helped me while I was a teenager is the statement “ who ever leave for Allah sake Allah will reward him/her with something better” من ترك شيئا لله عوضه الله خيرا منه
And the reward is bigger when you leave a stronger desire for Allah sake!

Think about that if you have someone who is very dear to you ( someone you love too much ) and asked you to do/ donot something I believe you will listen to him/her right? Then how about the one who gave you all good things in your life the one who creates you.

May Allah helps you and guide you

Answer (score -3):

Repeat YA-KHABIR  it is the name of Allah, if someone is a victim of selfish desire or bad habits andhe/she want to get rid of bad habits then ones must repeat this beautiful name of Allah AL-KHABIR which means THE AWARE!